# Как писать сообщения от имени бота, telebot, python

Tags: python, telebot

Мне нужна команда бота /msg (/msg TEXT) для отправки сообщений от имени бота.  И команда /msgU для отправки на один ID (/msgU 123456 TEXT). Все ID пользователей хранятся в txt файле. Как это можно сделать? Зарание спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш текстовый файл с ID выглядит вот так:

```
23323232232
23323254355
35455355353
```

То вот:

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    text=message.text
    mesage=text.split()


    if mesage[0]=='/msg':
        mesage.remove(mesage[0])
        text = ' '.join(mesage)
        with open('Ваш фаил') as f:
            lines = list(f)
            
        for i in lines:

            if '\n' in i:
                i = i[0:-1]
   


            bot.send_message(i,text)
    elif mesage[0] == '/msgu':
        id = mesage[1]
        mesage.remove(mesage[0])
        mesage.remove(mesage[0])
        text = ' '.join(mesage)

        bot.send_message(id, text)
```

Ну и можно сделать чтобы только на твои команды реагировал:

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    if message.chat.id == твой ID
        text=message.text
        mesage=text.split()

    
        if mesage[0]=='/msg':
            mesage.remove(mesage[0])
            text = ' '.join(mesage)
            with open('3.txt') as f:
                lines = list(f)
                print(lines)
            for i in lines:

                if '\n' in i:
                    i = i[0:-1]
                print(i)


                bot.send_message(i,text)
        elif mesage[0] == '/msgu':
            id = mesage[1]
            mesage.remove(mesage[0])
            mesage.remove(mesage[0])
            text = ' '.join(mesage)

            bot.send_message(id, text)
```

И на будущие используй базы данных

Comment: Спасибо! Но сработал только 1 вариант кода! Про БД учту!